# Inputing text into labels with for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, label

let's say I'm having 10 labels called "Label1", "Label2", "Label3".... "Label10".
Is there a way to make a for loop which I could enter text for each Label its number?

I mean - Label1.Text will be "1". Label2.Text will be 2 , and so on till Label10.Text will be 10.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

in your `.cshtml` file you could do:

```
@{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        var labelId = "Label" + i;
        var labelText = "LabelText" + i;

        <label id="@labelId">@labelText</label><br />
    }

}
```

which results in:

[image]